# Is finally block really necessary for the clean up code (like closing streams)?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch-finally

I am very confused as to why do I need to need to put the clean-up code like closing streams in a `finally` block.

I've read that the code in `finally` block will run no matter what (whether there's an exception); and after the `finally` block runs, the rest of the method continues.

My question is: if the rest of the method has to continue then why don't I put the clean-up code after my try/catch block in a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The finally block will always run if an uncaught exception is thrown, but the rest of the code in the method will be skipped.

So if you put clean-up code after the finally block, it won't get called if there is an exception.

Comment: so does it means that if my catch blocks aren't able to handle the thrown exceptions(i.e an uncaught exception) only then finally block has an importance?  Thanks

Comment: Correct. If you catch and handle the exception then execution will continue normally. But even if you are sure that you will catch all exceptions (a dangerous assumption...) it's still good practice to put your clean-up code in the `finally` block.

Comment: Ankit, no, even if you `catch Throwable`, you'll **still** need the services of the `finally` block.

Answer (score 11):

> My question is; if the rest of the method has to continue then why do I not put the clean-up code after my try/catch block in a function.

Basically, like this:

```
InputStream is = ...
try {
   // use stream
} catch (IOException ex) {
   // report / recover
}
is.close();
```

But what happens if the `// use stream` section throws a different (e.g. unchecked) exception?  Or the `// report / recover` code?  In either case the `close()` call doesn't happen.  (And what if there is a `break` or `return` statement in those blocks?)

It is possible to implement it this way in theory.  The problem is making sure that the code always (i.e. ALWAYS) runs.  And it is difficult to do that without catching a whole bunch of exceptions that you shouldn't be catching ... and won't be able to deal with properly if you do catch.

All in all, `finally` is the better solution.

- it is simpler than the convolutions you otherwise need to do to handle the situation properly, and
- it is more reliable than a typical half-hearted attempt.

And it is even simpler / more reliable if you can use the new Java 7 "try with resources" form in which the `finally` is taken care of automatically.

---

I would add that your characterization of when the `finally` clause is executed is a bit inaccurate.  In reality, the `finally` block is executed no matter how the try block terminates, including:

- when the `try` block drops off the end,
- when it throws an exception ... irrespective of whether the exception is caught at this level, or
- when it executes a `return`, `continue` or `break`.

In fact, the *only* cases where the `finally` block does not execute are if the `try` block calls `System.exit()` or the JVM crashes.  (Or if it goes into an infinite loop ...)

Comment: Not just always runs, but **never runs twice**. Even worse problem without `finally`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - true, though a lot of clean up actions (like closing streams) can safely be run twice ... 'cos the APIs are specified to allow this.

Comment: I used to get an `StreamAlreadyClosedException` from a `GzippedInputStream` or some such :)

Comment: That is weird.  GZIPInputStream implements Closeable, and the javadoc for the `close()` method in `Closeable` specifically states that closing a closed stream is a no-op.

Comment: It was some such then, sorry I can't remember exactly. It is a Spring JEE project deployed to WebSphere, using customized Spring HTTP Remoting. It could turn out that it was some custom code and not a library after all.

Answer (score 3):

In case you encounter an unexpected exception (not caught and handled).

Comment: This is the only useful thing to say. Neat and exhaustive.

Answer (score 1):

> after the finally block runs rest of the method continues

This is only true if there was no exception caught. If an exception happens inside the try block the catch block will be executed (if there is one for this exception), the finally block will be executed, and then control is given to the caller of the method if the catch block throws the exception further, *without* running any further code in this method.

EDIT: clarify that catch would have to return of course, and not just eat the exception.

Comment: Come on... clearly a **false statement**! What about the code that follows the try-catch block?

Comment: Indeed, forgot the "catch ignores or properly handles exception". sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If an `Exception` occurs, ie, the try block is executed, then, rest assured, the `finally` block will also be executed. It's just a safeguard option instead of putting an unreliable assumption that the rest of the method will get executed.

Answer (score 1):

> if the rest of the method has to continue then why do I not put the
>   clean-up code after my try/catch block in a function.

Because the clean-up of your code is related to your `try` to do an action that attempts to  open resources etc and logically it should be as part of the `final` clause as it is the last action related to your `try`.
It would not make sense for example to close a file or connection 100 lines later due to some processing you have to do before returning.
You got the results. No exception, release the resources. Best to do it in `finally` so that your code is cleaner as it is always executed

Answer (score 0):

> My question is; if the rest of the method has to continue then why not I put the clean code after my try/catch block in a function.

You can do so but you have to call this function again in finally block by passing object references( non-java resources) that needs to be closed. Because if this function is not finally block and if any exception occurs your entire method will be skipped without closing non-java reources.

Also you can use java7 feature -> [try-catch with resources](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/07/java-7-try-with-resources-explained.html). Non-java resources will be automatically closed. You do not need to use finally block.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a slight misunderstanding here (or this is myself who misunderstand). The finally block is run whether a method exits on exceptional conditions or not, e.g.

```
 try {
      throw new Exception();
 }
 finally {
      // Block of code will be called before the method exits as exception is thrown
 }
```

Note that there is (very) few exception to this rule, as, for instance:

```
 try {
      System.exit(-1);
 }
 finally {
      // Block of code will be called before the method exits as exception is thrown
 }
```

This is a (quite dangerous) case where the program will exit *without* executing the finally block.

Comment: The exceptions to the rule are: 1) `System.exit()`, 2) calling some exit syscall or similar in native code, 3) JVM panic, 4) JVM hard-killed by OS, 5) Hardware or power failure.  You just have to know that these things are possible.

Answer (score 0):

finally block as good for people as for compiler.

Take in to attention not only compiler but also human who will read your code.
It would be much easy to edit code if clean-up part is in the finally block.

Answer (score 0):

Finally Block will 100% surely execute try/catch will  completely execute or Not.

So if u want to release the system resources u write the code in finally block.
and return statements of the methods also.

Answer (score 0):

A `finally` block will do the job. But if you want to improve the security which avoids resources 'leaking' when the `gc` runs, I recommend you use try-with-resources it is neater and more efficient.

For more information check this
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html